# In wso2 ESb how to call a TCP server/how to establish tcp connection

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB I want to call a TCP server. In the below sample code I tried to call but I got exception in tcp server and it is not connecting.

```
<api context="/ex" name="ex" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="POST">
    <inSequence>
        <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
        <log level="full"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="value"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="tcp://ipaddress:9090"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

java code for TCP server which prints message rescived.

```
public class ser {


    public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
    {   
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
            System.out.println("wainting for clients...");
            boolean stop = false;
            //while(!stop)

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("Hello  client!");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String clientInput = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientInput);
            input.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

As ESB api is POST request, I am calling in postaman(restclient) with text/plain having message **hello**.

But when i call from ESB through restclient, I'm getting these exceptions in in server socket

**java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed**

SO, how to establish tcp connection in wso2 esb.

Comment: Have you added Transport sender and transport receiver in axis2.xml file ? If not then add them.<transportReceiver name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener" />
<transportSender name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender"/>   , After this first try creating a proxy service and see if the connection to TCP is happening or not [ <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6789</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">application/xml</parameter>]

Comment: i have configured these in ESB, that's why I'm not getting any exception in ESB. I'm getting exception in server socket.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation and the client implementation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/TCP+Transport